# How to send data from a list loaded by <s:iterator>

Tags: jsp, iterator, struts2

I was wondering that how could I get one of my data from a list loaded by `<s:iterator>`. iπ can see all of them on the website but I want to modify one of them. Below is my JSP page code. I want to get the `trabsaction` and `exCode`.

```
<s:iterator  value="batchJobDoList" status="stat" var="each" >  
    
    <!--CCC -->
    <s:if test="#stat.odd">
    
        <tr class="Detail1" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';"
            onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='';">
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
         <tr class="Detail2" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';"
            onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='';">
    </s:else>
    

                            
    
    <td id="colseq">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#stat.index+1+((currentPage-1)*pageSize)"/></div>
        </td>
        <!-- <td id="colseq"><div align="center"><s:property value="#stat.index+1"/></div></td> -->
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#each.transaction" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"style="width: 200px;"><s:property value="#each.exCode" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#each.createTime" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#each.startTime" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#each.endTime" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <div align="center"><s:property value="#each.status" /></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdate" type="button" value='<s:text name="button.modify">update</s:text>' class="actionButton" 
             onclick="toModLog('<s:property value="%{(#stat.index + 1) + ((currentPage - 1) * dataPage.pageSize)}"/>');"/>
        </td>
            
    </tr>   
    </s:iterator>
```

I have tried some ways to get them like, set up an `<s:hidden>` to put the `transaction` inside and take it with javascript `var XX = $(XX).value()` or put them into a form when I click on `update` send the form to my action. Both of them did not work out

I want to know how can I do to get the data I want in `<s:iterator>`.

Comment: It is not clear where do you want to get them, in the JSP, JavaScript, or in the action? You didn't post the code to submit the action, nor the action class to get the data.